Git commit the file currently being edited in VS Code
Is there an easy way in VS Code to commit only the file you are currently editing? I mean GUI equivalent for git commit pathspec where pathspec is the file currently being edited (and saved).
man git-commit:

When pathspec is given on the command line, commit the contents of the files that match the pathspec without recording the changes already added to the index.

I'm looking for no more than two mouse clicks or keystrokes to open something where I can write a commit message for the file I'm currently editing.

Why is using the command line not "easy"?

@matt, that's pretty easy, but I'd like something even easier, e.g. having a single keyboard shortcut to open a commit message dialog for the file being edited, or git commit -m "<cursor blinks here>" path/to/file in a terminal.

@0stone0, I'm looking for no more than two mouse clicks or keystrokes to open something where I can write a commit message for the file I'm currently editing.

Then learn how to use the git command line, it won't get any easier then that.

Isn't there a feature in VS Code where you can just tick a checkbox on a file on the left (edit: it's a + button) and click a "Commit" button?

@0stone0 I mostly use git command line but sometimes I want to commit a single file and 1. copy path into clipboard, 2. switch to terminal, 3. type git commit -m "something" path/from/clipboard takes time more than I'm looking for.

@mkrieger1 Yes, that's possible but when there's a lot of files being changed it's not easy to find one currently being edited.

I wrote a VS Code feature request for a command: Git: Commit Active File.

Since you won't get a useful answer here, you might wish to delete the question.

@haba713 "it's not easy to find one currently being edited" Then you don't have Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" checked.

@matt :) I'll add an answer if the feature is implemented.

I don't quite understand why my question got downvotes. If there are no easier ways to commit an active file than those mentioned, isn't that also useful for readers to know? And if someone comes up with an easy way later, or the requested feature is implemented, wouldn't that be useful information too?

@LokiRagnarok, the question is about VS Code, not Visual Studio.

Currently there's no easier way than those suggested in the discussion under the question:

How can I commit some changes to a file, but not others, in VSCode?


Copy the file path into clipboard.
Switch to terminal.
type git commit -m "your message" path/from/clipboard



I wrote a VS Code feature request for a command "Git: Commit Active File" and will update this answer if the feature is implemented.
